# Unable to connect to server: Host name may not be null

Tags: docker, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am taking the below wso2 course.

[Course Link](https://lms.wso2.com/courses/video-live-training-wso2-api-manager-developer-fundamentals-english)

**This is the video:**

> In Cloud Native API Management with WSO2 API Manager - an Overview
> Lab 4 - Using a microgateway (10min)

As I used this command, the docker image is not created in the local properly.

```
micro-gw build Petstore --deployment-config E:\wso2-CertificatonPreparation\micorgateway-projects\Petstore\deployment.toml
```

I am getting the below error. Please help me to resolve this issue.

`Generating docker artifacts...`

`error [docker plugin]: module [wso2/Petstore:3.1.0] unable to connect to server:Host name may not be null`

And also,

What should I configure in **target of deployment.toml**

source =`E:/wso2-CertificatonPreparation/wso2-softwares/wso2am-micro-gw-toolkit-windows-3.1.0/resources/conf/micro-gw.conf`

**target = `/home/ballerina/conf/micro-gw.conf`**

I am using version 3.1.0

This is the deployment.toml

```
[docker]
    [docker.dockerConfig]
        enable = true
        name = " petstore "
        registry = ' docker.wso2.com '
        tag = ' v1 '
        #buildImage = ''
        #dockerHost = ''
        #dockerCertPath = ''
        baseImage = 'wso2/wso2micro-gw:3.0.2'
        #enableDebug = ''
        #debugPort = ''
        #push = ''
    [docker.dockerCopyFiles]
        enable = true
        [[docker.dockerCopyFiles.files]]
        source ='E:/wso2-CertificatonPreparation/wso2-softwares/wso2am-micro-gw-toolkit-windows-3.1.0/resources/conf/micro-gw.conf'
        target = '/home/ballerina/conf/micro-gw.conf'
        isBallerinaConf = true
```

Comment: It appears that you've added spaces around the hostname.

Comment: Are you referring this as hostname ( registry = ' docker.wso2.com ' ).Even i removed space around it , i am getting the same error.

Comment: Generating docker artifacts...
error [docker plugin]: module [wso2/Petstore:3.1.0] unable to connect to server:    Host name may not be null

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Answer (score 0):

Can you check with this config?. This works for me without any issue.

```html
[docker]
  [docker.dockerConfig]
    enable = true
    name = "petstore"
    registry = 'docker.wso2.com'
    tag = 'v1'
    #buildImage = ''
    #dockerHost = ''
    #dockerCertPath = ''
    baseImage = 'wso2/wso2micro-gw:3.0.2'
    #enableDebug = ''
    #debugPort = ''
    #push = ''
    username = '####'
    password = '####'
  [docker.dockerCopyFiles]
    enable = true
    [[docker.dockerCopyFiles.files]]
        source = '/Users/hasunie/RD/UI/wso2am-micro-gw-toolkit-macos-3.1.0/resources/conf/micro-gw.conf'
        target = '/home/ballerina/conf/micro-gw.conf'
        isBallerinaConf = true
```

Comment: Is there any configuration file we need to specify host name for Docker?   I am using windows 10 Professional with Docker Desktop

Comment: i used your configuration file, still facing the same issue.

Comment: what is the use of target in the deployment.toml

Comment: source is the file location in your machine. Target is the destination that file gets copied in the docker container. Target is correct. Have you installed docker in your machine? Can you list down images by using the command docker images?